# Consuming a WCF Service in Mono?

Tags: wcf, mono, wcf-binding

I am trying to consume a WCF Webservice on Mono using the proxy but I am getting the following exception:

> System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
>     at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.WSHttpBindingElement.OnApplyConfiguration (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.9/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Configuration/WSHttpBindingElement.cs:101 
>     at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.StandardBindingElement.ApplyConfiguration (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding) [0x00030] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.9/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Configuration/StandardBindingElement.cs:143 
>     at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ConfigUtil.CreateBinding (System.String binding, System.String bindingConfiguration) [0x00053] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.9/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Configuration/ConfigUtil.cs:102 
>     at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration (System.String endpointConfig) [0x000d9] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.9/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ChannelFactory.cs:134 
>     at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint (System.String endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) [0x00024] in /private/tmp/monobuild/build/BUILD/mono-2.10.9/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ChannelFactory.cs:309

I am not sure exactly what this is but I take it that it probably is to do with Mono not supporting authentication in WCF Webservices.

I need to be able to consume this WCF webservice on Mono or Ubuntu somehow. What are my options?

Is there something else that I can use to access it as a SOAP service and bypass using the .Net WCF code?

Comment: If you try it with out authentication does it supports all your needs? I assume you are aware that Mono is not mature enough in consuming WCF services.

Comment: I do not own this webservice. It is provided by a corporate company so I doubt that it can be used without authentication. Is there any other way to consume the webservice? It is based on SOAP so maybe I can use it as a SOAP webservice?

Comment: Are you limited at using Mono? If you are familiar with other technologies as Java that would help you a lot.

Comment: This is a possibility but I would like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer based on the information provided by you. As long as the WCF service respects the established industry standards WS-* you can consume it as SOAP service. I am not sure how evolved is Mono in order to provide you a ready running client, but according to your issues it is seems features are missing. In that case I assume you will have to do some plumbing on your own.

Comment: Do you know of any examples out there of consuming WCF as a SOAP service in .NET?

Comment: Not really since most of the .NET clients are making use of the WSDL to generate the proxy. The only one of which I am aware of is http://soap-sec.sourceforge.net/. Not sure it will satisfy you needs but you could use it as starting point.