# Mono WCF Client Exception: The requested feature is not implemented

Tags: linux, wcf, mono, monodevelop, redhat

I have developed a C# WCF client application using Visual Studio 2008 and it works fine. The client application uses the wcf wrapper class and consume the WCF service. But when I execute the same source code in Redhat Linux  6.5 using MonoDevelop IDE, I am getting the following exception while creating a wcf object. The WCF web service is running as a windows service.

> {System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.WSHttpBindingElement.OnApplyConfiguration (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding) [0x00000] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Configuration/WSHttpBindingElement.cs:101    at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.StandardBindingElement.ApplyConfiguration (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding) [0x00030] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Configuration/StandardBindingElement.cs:143    at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ConfigUtil.CreateBinding (System.String binding, System.String bindingConfiguration) [0x00053] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Configuration/ConfigUtil.cs:104    at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration (System.String endpointConfig) [0x000e9] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ChannelFactory.cs:156    at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint (System.String endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) [0x00024] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ChannelFactory.cs:309    at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[IMyMonitor]..ctor (System.String endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) [0x00017] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ChannelFactory_1.cs:73    at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[IMyMonitor].Initialize (System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instance, System.String endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) [0x00000] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientBase.cs:159    at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[IMyMonitor]..ctor (System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instance, System.String endpointConfigurationName) [0x00028] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientBase.cs:90    at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[IMyMonitor]..ctor (System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instance) [0x00000] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientBase.cs:79    at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[IMyMonitor]..ctor () [0x00000] in /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/mono-3.4.0/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ClientBase.cs:54    at SenMonitorClient..ctor () [0x00000] in /mywork/myclient/wcfService.cs:1429    at myclient.start () [0x0079c] in /mywork/myclient/Program.cs:285 }    System.NotImplementedException

**Environment:** MonoDevelop 4.2.3, mono 3.4.0

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Consuming a WCF Service in Mono?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287914/consuming-a-wcf-service-in-mono)

Comment: @chuex, do you mean duplicate in the client code

Comment: It's a duplicate in the sense that Mono's implementation is incomplete, and that is what the accepted answer in the other question is stating. Also, your stack trace seems to be identical to the other one.

Comment: @HPFE455 - There were known issues with WS-Security implementation of Mono and looks like it is persisting with 3.4.0. What is the binding type/security mode? You may have to check those while porting it to Mono.

Comment: @Thinkster, binding type is WSHttpBinding. Instead of using the wrapper, can I consume the web service directly using some other way?

Comment: I found the above question which posted on 2012, I thought this issue might be fixed now.

Comment: WCF support is currently limited on Mono and as mentioned here - http://www.mono-project.com/WCF WSHttpBinding and its dependencies are components with no plan to support. May be you want to fall back on to basichttpbinding which should be supported since it shows WCF modules were in development till .NET 3.0 with silverlight 2.0 subset.

Comment: @Thinkster, thanks I will try to use basichttpbinding

Comment: @Thinkster - basichttpbinding is working. Please add your comment as answer. I have to find a workaround to make is work with WS*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF support is currently limited on Mono and as mentioned here - mono-project.com/WCF WSHttpBinding and its dependencies are components with no plan to support. May be you want to fall back on to  `basichttpbinding` which should be supported since it shows WCF modules were in development till .NET 3.0 with silverlight 2.0 subset.